# Why does x^(-1/0) = 0

Tags: haskell, math

The expression x^(1/0) results in undefined, and I suppose x^(-1/0) = 1/x^(1/0), but why does this equal 0? What exponent rule is at play here?

I thought (1/0) always returns undefined, so why would there be a difference if this exponent is in the numerator or denominator?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I use Haskell. 1 ** (1/0) = Infinity but 1 ** (-1/0) = 0.0. Is this is a limit of the language or is it mathematically sound?

Comment: I'm not sure if you knew this, but "undefined" has a very strong connotation in Haskell, and `1/0 :: Double` is not undefined in this standard sense. This makes the question confusing at best, or based on a wrong assumption if you actually intended it the way it sounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FPU rules. 1/0 in floating point results in +INF, and you have -1/0 which results in -INF. Anything to the -INF power is going to be zero.

Comment: Nitpick: Anything > 1 to the -INF power is going to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically the `limit of x tending to 0 of 1/x is infinity`.

Under this scope you can think of `1/0` as a huge number `(hn)`.

So the function `x^(-1/0)` which is the same as `1/(xˆ(hn))` can be looked at like this:

```
for x = 0, 0 to any power is still 0 

for (0 < x < 1), x^(hn) will tend to be 0, hence we end up with 1/0 which tends to infinity.

for x = 1, xˆ(hn) will be 1

for x > 1, x^(hn) will tend to also be huge number, hence we end up with 1/(hn) which tends to be 0
```

So the simple result of `x^(-1/0) = 0` is not mathematically correct